# How can I detect focus on child view inside a Tabbed Page in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I have a TabbedPage, which includes 3 pages (A,B,C). I need to detect (using some override method) when a page is active/selected from tabbed control. I tried some override methods such us OnAppearing with no result, because during debugging process I noticed OnAppearing was fired when TabbedPage was firstly initialized, so when I selected for example the second page (page B) this method was not fired. Is there any optimal way to detect switching between tabs inside child view?

Comment: TabbedPage inherits from [MultPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.multipage-1?view=xamarin-forms), which has `event CurrentPageChanged`. In your tabbedpage constructor, use `this.CurrentPageChanged += ...` to attach an `event handler` to that event. If you press `Tab` key after `+=`, Visual Studio should create an event handler for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like
ToolmakerSteve sayed, the tabbedpage has the CurrentPageChanged event, so you can override the `OnCurrentPageChanged()` method of the TabbedPage. Such as:

```
public partial class TabbedPage1 : TabbedPage
{
    public TabbedPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       
    }

    protected override void OnCurrentPageChanged()
    {
        
        if(CurrentPage == Children[0])//Children[0] is the page A
        {
            ....
        }else if(CurrentPage == Children[1])//Children[1] is the page B
        {
             .....
        }
        else
        {
            ......
        }
            

        base.OnCurrentPageChanged();
    }
}
```